# What are the disadvantage of having a lot of dynamic URLs in Nodejs-ExpressJs server

Tags: node.js, performance, url, express

Currently I am working with ExpressJs and NodeJs. My question is, If I have a lot of dynamically registered URLs in server (using app.get("/xyz", page.xyz)), what are the issues associated with it? Will it affect performance or memory usages of server?

Regards,
Harikrishnan

Answer (score 0):

Disadvantages:

1. you're probably repeating a lot of code
2. manageability of your methods
3. improper design patterns
4. larger code base affects performance
5. easier to performance measure
6. more manageable in a team setting
7. easier/more manageable to add features

Advantages:

1. explicit
2. potentially less functions utilized (i.e. per call)
3. more small data passed on the wire
4. easier to debug
5. easier to read by you

There shouldn't be an outright need for many endpoints, however, that's kind of your decision. It boils down to whether or not the app works, meeting deadlines, and of course you can performance test to see whether or not areas in your app could improve with design patterns or different data structures. This is a tough question to answer, however, I'd suggest you look at the process as a learning opportunity with the expectation to improve on your following iteration or next app. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer aug2aug